# How are we able to change this instance after it has been initialised?

Tags: javascript

```js
let f = function () {
  this.a = 1;
}

let o = new f(); 
console.log(o);

f.prototype.b = 2;

console.log(o);
```

Is it not weird that the line `f.prototype.b = 2;` manages to add this to `o` (make one of the properties of `o.__proto__` `{b: 2}`) after `o` has been initialised?

Comment: No, because the prototype is an object in its own right. Each property of an object is looked up every time an object is referenced, so "b" will be found via the *prototype chain*.

Comment: I had this notion that `o` had already been 'captured' with the `new f()` line. Now I have to think `o.__proto__` really does just point towards `f.prototype`. Is the JavaScript feature of 'reference data-types' coming into play? I.e. because `f` is a function (which is a reference data-type), when `f` is assigned to `o`, `o` simply points back to where `f` was originally initialised? There's never a `copy` made of `f` at the point in time in which `f` is assigned to `o`.

Comment: Changing the prototype object does *not* directly change the object `o`.  You can illustrate this by checking what `o.getOwnPropertyNames()` returns. The expression `o.b` works because after not finding `b` directly on `o`, the runtime checks the prototype object for a property called "b".

Comment: If instead of modifying the existing prototype object, you gave `f` a completely *new* prototype, then you would not be able to find `o.b` because the old prototype object reference was "captured", as you said.